# How do I convince Django I'm logged in?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cookies

I have a Django application and I want to allow users to log in via some API and allow them to use some API calls that are protected by `login_required` decorator:

```
@csrf_exempt
def api_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse(status=201)
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()

@login_required
def do_stuff(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

And this is how I try to log in and call `do_stuff` from python shell:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
>>> post = Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', urlencode({'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}).encode())
>>> post_resp = urlopen(post)
```

So far so good. I get a response with `sessionid` and `csrftoken` cookies. Then I try to use the `sessionid` cookie to do stuff:

```
>>> get = Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/do-stuff')
>>> get.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'csrftoken=...')  # just copy paste of the response cookie
>>> get_resp = urlopen(get)
```

At this point `login_required` decorator thinks I'm an `AnonimousUser` and sends out a redirect to the login page. Browser works perfectly with this `sessionid` cookie, so I suppose I miss some headers, because they aren't numerous, just `Host`, `User-Agent`, and `Set-Cookie`.

I'm deliberately trying to avoid using modules outside of Django and stdlib. Shouldn't authentication be rather simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that `Set-Cookie` is a wrong header for consequent requests. `Cookie` should be used instead:

```
>>> get = Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/do-stuff')
>>> get.add_header('Cookie', 'csrftoken=53eX5pwRzV4fR...')  # just csrftoken here
>>> get_resp = urlopen(get)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Django's test client instead of urllib.

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response = c.get('/customer/details/')
>>> response.content
b'<!DOCTYPE html...'
```

See: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client)

Comment: Hm, this looks very promising! Do you happen to know, can I ship `Client` as a standalone package (without the rest of Django)? And is it suitable for production?

Comment: Sorry...I have never tried to use it as a standalone package...And maybe it should only be used in the testing process.